# how can i have select inside insert into?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the Mysql im trying to run but its not working

```
INSERT into agent_daily_stats (date,login_id,emails_handled,chats_handled) 
VALUES (
  '5/1/2022 12:00:00 AM',
   SELECT login_id FROM ic_agent where login_name = rani_azzam,
  2,
  2
)
```

Comment: Define _Not Working_ more precisely please

Comment: Try to put your select in brackets and quote rani_azzam if this is no column name.

Comment: If the `date` column is a DATETIME data type then that date format is wrong. If `date` is not a DATETIME column then your design is wrong

Comment: is `rani_azzam` a string or a column?

Comment: Does `login_name` column is defined as UNIQUE in `ic_agent`?

Answer (score 1):

Making a few assumptions with a valid date and string literal for the login_name and that you only want to insert if the row exists, you can simply include all your columns as a `select`

```
INSERT into agent_daily_stats (date, login_id, emails_handled, chats_handled) 
SELECT '2022-05-01 00:00:00', login_id, 2, 2
FROM ic_agent 
WHERE login_name = 'rani_azzam';
```

Answer (score -1):

If there are more inserts with different login_names then query can be modified as below.

```
INSERT into agent_daily_stats (date,login_id,emails_handled,chats_handled) 
VALUES ('2022-05-01 00:00:00',(SELECT login_id from loginid where login_name = rani_azzam),2,2)
```

Same can be viewed on [db<>fiddle<>example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1582c0e1d6a51faa106ea0e596ceccf1)

Comment: Forgot to add the where condition as i was testing the same in the example attached @Akina